# What is the direct python/pandas equivalent of R/caret's str function, for factors?

Tags: python, r, pandas, r-caret

I would specifically like a function that displays the levels for a factor/categorical variable, as does str() in R/caret.

For example, in R we have:

```
data(iris)
str(iris)
## 'data.frame':    150 obs. of  5 variables:
##  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
##  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
##  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
##  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
##  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

How would I accomplish this exactly in python/pandas?

Neither `dataFrame.describe()` nor `dataFrame.info()` would get this right for `iris$Species`.

Comment: Note that `str` is a base R function and is unrelated to the `caret` package with the exception that `caret` may implement some additional methods for `str`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simplest would be

```
df.Species.value_counts()
```

Comment: how to apply across all Series within the data frame? `[p.x.value_counts() for x in p]` is a little ugly

Comment: that s not ugly at all and thats the only way buddy

Comment: Hence, [p.x.value_counts() for x in p if p.x.dtype == 'category' else p.x] or something.